# CMD command set temporary variable question

Tags: java, cmd

I try below code to set temporary variable I expect test value is FirstSecond. But in fact value is %test%Second.How can i get first test value?

```
  String[] testCmd= new String[]{
                "cmd.exe",
                "/c",
                "set test=First & set test=%test%Second & set test",//I expect test value is FirstSecond. But in fact value is %test%Second 

        };
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(mavenCmd);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = builder.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(),  Charset.forName("GBK")));
        String line = null;
        
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that cmd works like this:

1. Read line
2. Do variable substitutions
3. Split line into commands
4. Execute commands

and you want variable substitution to happen immediately before execution.

You can instead write

```
set test=First & set test=!test!Second & set test
```

using the delayed-substitution operator '!'
but this must be executed with delayed-substitution enabled

```
cmd  /v:on
```

Thus

```
C:\> set t=one & set t=!t!two & set t
t=one two
```

(that space in the result is kind of interesting)

Comment: The 'piece' before the first ampersand is `set t=one<sp>` and the space is included in the value set, and subsequently expanded. `set "t=one"<sp>` will omit it. (But `set t="one"<sp>` won't.)

Comment: where should `/v:on` place in? like this `["cmd.exe","/v:on","set t=one & set t=!t!two & set t"]` is not work

Comment: As well as quotes suggested by @dave_thompson_085
, simply dropping the space before ampersand also removes the trailing spaces from the value `set t=one& set t=!t!two& set t`

Comment: This works interactively.  `cmd /v:on /c "set t=1&set t=!t!2&set t"` , so try this in your program. The quotes are important, as is the order of /v and /c.